# Master-Detail Relationship - Process Builder

Tags: process-builder, master-detail

I have a **Custom Object = A**, **another Custom Object = B** *in a master detail relationship* and the **Account Object**.

I want to be able to make **checkbox = true on the Account**, *depending on some criteria on Custom Object = B.* *To mention: the checkbox is unchecked by default and based on Edit - Save, it gets automatically checked.*

- If custom field 1 = "Inbound" and custom field 2 = not blank, to make the checkbox = true on Account

  ```
   ***custom field 1** = text formula looking back at picklist field on Custom Object = A
   ***custom field 2** = text field
   ***there is a lookup field from custom object B to the Account that gets populated through a before trigger.**
  ```

What I have tried to do initially:

1. Create a Process on Custom Object B - to start only when a record is created.
2. check if custom field 2 = Global Constant = .Null AND custom field = formula "inbound", but it didn't work.

So I have also tried:

1. Create a Process on Custom Object A - to start only when a record is created.
2. Check custom field 3 = picklist = inbound
3. I have created an invocable process on Custom Object B to call as an action in the process on Custom Object A, but the field reference is not helpful - created by, last modified by, owner id, etc.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Would a COUNT roll-up summary field work? You can count the number of detail objects that have the field set and then have a formula on the Account that reflects when the count is 1 or "1 or more" (depending on your use-case).

Comment: @nbrown - That's amazing. Thank you. I will give that a go and come back to you :)